# How to correctly display user's info among multiple users?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The command to retrieve user data doesn't display correctly, it shows the information of the last registered user.

**MainActivity/login**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnRegister, btnLogin;
    EditText edtAccount, edtPassword;
    Database db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        edtAccount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAccount);
        edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);


        db=new Database(this);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String account = edtAccount.getText().toString();
                String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

                if (account.equals("") || password.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Account and password are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Boolean result = db.checkUserNamePassword(account, password);
                    if(result==true) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("account", account);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                    else{
                        Boolean userCheckResult = db.checkUserName(account);
                        if(userCheckResult == true){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "invalid password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            edtPassword.setError("invalid password!");
                        } else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Account does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            edtAccount.setError("Account does not exist!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Database**

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TB_USER = "USER";
    public static final String TB_PERSONAL = "PERSONAL";
    public static final String TB_GROUPSCHEDULE = "GROUPSCHEDULE";

    public static String TB_USER_ACCOUNT = "ACCOUNT";
    public static String TB_USER_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";


    public static String TB_USER_ID = "USERID";
    public static String TB_USER_FIRSTNAME = "USERFIRSTNAME";
    public static String TB_USER_LASTNAME = "USERLASTNAME";
    public static String TB_USER_PHONENUMBER = "PHONENUMBER";
    public static String TB_USER_EMAIL = "EMAIL";

    public static String TB_PERSONAL_ID = "PERSONALID";
    public static String TB_PERSONAL_TIME = "PERSONALTIME";
    public static String TB_PERSONAL_EVENT = "PERSONALEVENT";

    public static String TB_GROUP_ID = "GROUPID";
    public static String TB_GROUP_MEMBERS = "GROUPMEMBERS";
    public static String TB_GROUP_LEADER = "GROUPLEADER";
    public static String TB_GROUP_EVENT = "GROUPEVENT";
    public static String TB_GROUP_TIME = "GROUPTIME";


    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, "Mysche", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String tbUSER = " CREATE TABLE " + TB_USER + " ( "
                + TB_USER_ACCOUNT + " TEXT , "
                + TB_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT , "
                + TB_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TB_USER_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT, "
                + TB_USER_LASTNAME + " TEXT, "
                + TB_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                + TB_USER_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT )";

        String tbPERSONAL = " CREATE TABLE " + TB_PERSONAL + " ( "
                + TB_PERSONAL_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY , "
                + TB_PERSONAL_EVENT + " TEXT, "
                + TB_PERSONAL_TIME + " DATE )";

        String tbGROUP = " CREATE TABLE " + TB_GROUPSCHEDULE + " ( "
                + TB_GROUP_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "
                + TB_GROUP_LEADER + " TEXT, "
                + TB_GROUP_MEMBERS + " TEXT, "
                + TB_GROUP_EVENT + " TEXT, "
                + TB_GROUP_TIME + " TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(tbUSER);
        db.execSQL(tbPERSONAL);
        db.execSQL(tbGROUP);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_USER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_PERSONAL);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_GROUPSCHEDULE);
        
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Boolean insertData(String ACCOUNT, String PASSWORD, String USERFIRSTNAME, String USERLASTNAME, String PHONENUMBER, String EMAIL) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("ACCOUNT", ACCOUNT);
        contentValues.put("PASSWORD", PASSWORD);
        contentValues.put("USERFIRSTNAME", USERFIRSTNAME);
        contentValues.put("USERLASTNAME", USERLASTNAME);
        contentValues.put("PHONENUMBER", PHONENUMBER);
        contentValues.put("EMAIL", EMAIL);

        long result = db.insert("USER", null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Boolean checkUserName(String ACCOUNT) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ACCOUNT = ?"
                , new String[]{ACCOUNT});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean checkUserNamePassword(String ACCOUNT, String PASSWORD) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from USER where ACCOUNT = ? and PASSWORD = ?"
                , new String[]{ACCOUNT, PASSWORD});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getInfo() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER
                + " WHERE " + TB_USER_ACCOUNT, null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

**TestActivity**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Database database = new Database(this);
        TextView textViewName = findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
        TextView textViewEmail = findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
        TextView textViewPhone = findViewById(R.id.textViewPhone);
        TextView textViewAccount = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccount);
        
        String account = getIntent().getStringExtra("account");
        textViewPhone.setText(account);
        
        Cursor cursor = database.getInfo();
        
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            textViewName.setText(cursor.getString(4 ) + " " +(cursor.getString(3)));
            textViewPhone.setText(cursor.getString(5));
            textViewEmail.setText(cursor.getString(6));
            textViewAccount.setText(account);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need to change this command:

```
 public Cursor getInfo() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER
                + " WHERE " + TB_USER_ACCOUNT, null);
        return cursor;
}
```

to:

```
public Cursor getInfo() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER
            + " WHERE " + TB_USER_ACCOUNT + "=" + loggingAccount();, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

But I don't know how to create and insert that `loggingAccount()` function. I was able to display username by `getIntent()` in `TestActivity`.

```
String account = getIntent().getStringExtra("account");
textViewPhone.setText(account);
```

Or if anyone knows another way please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an overloaded method `getInfo(String acct)` and invoke as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = database.getInfo(account);
```

and define it as such:

```
public Cursor getInfo(String account) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER
            + " WHERE " + TB_USER_ACCOUNT + " = '" + account + "'", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

An overloaded [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) means methods within a class can have the same name (e.g. `getInfo`) but differ in method signature (parameters).  And of course their implementation can differ.

Since your query is formed using data from user input you should **use prepared statements**.  Check out [PreparedStatement](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for more discussion on that.